# Issue With Starting Rails Server & Creating a New Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and have finally been able to install rails and follow along with a video tutorial. I am having a couple issues. Yesterday I was not having any major issues. Then this morning when I tried to create another rails project I get an error or when I try to run my rails server for my last first project I get an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
/Users/lipmanb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/lipmanb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rails-4.2.3/bin/rails (LoadError)
from /Users/lipmanb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/lipmanb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/lipmanb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'.
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't have Rails installed on that environment. You may have installed Rails system wide, but since you are using RVM and you are within a Rails folder, you may be missing that specific Rails version.

Run bundler from within the Rails folder and install the required version.

```
$ bundler install
```

or simply

```
$ bundler
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved part of my issue. But I still get an error when I try to create a new rails app. https://gist.github.com/brandonlipman/80f7f9cd0e7134e23e3e

Comment: Reinstall Rails with `$ gem install rails` in the Ruby system environment.

Comment: When you say "Ruby system environment" do you mean at the top directory by using, `cd ~ ` or is this involving RVM?

Comment: Anywhere outside a Rails or bundler-based project.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your root directory `cd ~` and type the following:

```
sudo gem install rails
```